# Best way to store a complex key in a map?

Tags: java, hashmap

In java, keys of a `Map` work great if they are primitive, but it can be more complicated if they are not. For a `Map<String, Payload>` we are comparing primitive types and so if do a `map.put("key1", payload1)`, followed by a `map.get("key1")`, I"ll get my key.

This wouldn't work if my key is of the type `Map<MyEnumKey, Payload>`, unless I override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

In my situation, the key I have currently is an `enum` like this:

```
Map<MyEnumKey, String> map = Map.of(
    MyEnumKey.FIRST_KEY, "payload1"
    MyEnumKey.SECOND_KEY, "payload2"
);
```

But I'd like the map to be able to store more than 1 enum as the key. So something like a `List<MyEnumKey>` makes sense.

```
Map<..., String> map = Map.of(
    (MyEnumKey.FIRST_KEY, MyEnumKey.SOME_KEY), "payload1"
    MyEnumKey.SECOND_KEY, "payload2"
);
```

In this situation, what can be the best way to define the map without creating a separate class that encapsulates a `List<MyEnumKey>` and then overriding the `equals` and `hashcode`? Can this be solved in a "functional" manner?

Comment: You know you can have a `Map<List<MyEnumKey>, String>`, right?

Comment: Why do you think you the equals and hashCode methods of List somehow don't work in the context of a Map key? They work fine. The only potential pitfall is that Map keys must be immutable, so you should be careful not to add to the List after inserting, preferably using an immutable implementation that makes it impossible.

Comment: Why does this work without creating equals, hashCode with List<Enum> but not if I create an EnclosingEnumList<Enum> custom class ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<List<EnumKey>, String> someMap
```

Should do the trick.